# Ajax Post giving Internal Server Error 500 in IIS hosted Website

Tags: .net, ajax, post, iis-8, asp.net-mvc-5

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Home/ReadText",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            data: function () {
               var data = new FormData();
                data.append("file", jQuery("#file").get(0).files[0]);
               data.append("selected", drop);
               return data;
            }(),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
               debugger;
                $("#target").empty();
               $("#target").load("/Home/Results");


            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                console.log(errorMessage);
            }
        });
```

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReadText(HttpPostedFileBase file, string selected)
       {
     if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    Session["filename"] = fileName.Replace(".txt","");
                    string content = file.InputStream.ToString();
                    path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImages/"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    }
                string texts = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
                texts = texts.Replace(","," ");
                    string ofile = "names.txt";
                    string Spellpath= Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/MegTrans/"), ofile);
                    TextWriter tw1 = new StreamWriter(Spellpath, false, Encoding.Default);


                    tw1.WriteLine(texts);

                    tw1.Close();
Session["score"] = texts;
            return PartialView("Results");
       }
```

### Here returning a partial view and reloading the view in success function of ajax call. Its working properly when running locally, ReadText() method is giving Internal server error while making the ajax call on IIS hosted website

Stack trace of exception i got it from dev mode in Chrome.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Tesseract_MVC_Test.Controllers.HomeController.ReadText(HttpPostedFileBase file, String selected) +1675
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +190
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +228
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +68
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +71
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +386
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +69
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +186
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +399
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +157
```

Comment: Does it actually go into the code of the controller? Is the controller function ReadText actually blank server side or did you just not post the code. It would help to know what line of code was failing.

Comment: its working fine when i run it locally , after publishing this to iis i found this error using firebug

Comment: ReadText is not blank, its is braking in the ajax call, not hitting the controller, getting the Internal server 500 causing by null reference of the passed variable

Comment: I could be wrong but a System.NullReferenceException is a .net exception which would seem to indicate that the ajax call is making it to the server but something in the server .Net code is causing the exception.

Comment: Its is working well when running locally, is iis blocking the ajax call on hosted website?

Comment: I suppose,this exception  has nothing to do with the ajax call.

Comment: I don't think iis is blocking the ajax call, my guess would be that if it is running fine locally but not on the hosted website, there is an exception being thrown in the middle of the ReadText function that is causing an object to be set to null, but null isn't being checked before accessing a memer of that object, thus causing the null reference exception. However, without the code inside that controller function ReadText, it is impossible to point to what line of code might be causing the issue.

Comment: Its the code in your `ReadText()` method that is resulting in the error, and you have not shown it so no one can help you

Comment: The controller code

Comment: Error fixed, forgot to give full control permission for IIS_Users